# Jenkis: Not able to push to GCP Artifact registory

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline, google-artifact-registry

Getting Below error
**denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts"**

every thing works fine from base machine with same privilege.

```
WARNING: `docker-credential-gcloud` not in system PATH.
gcloud's Docker credential helper can be configured but it will not work until this is corrected.
```

Need Help !!

I tried to execute same command from base machine it works fine.

Able to connect artifact registry with same service account

Comment: I tried this on MAC-OS

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you will need to grant the necessary permissions to the service account. Specifically, you will need to grant the "Artifact Registry Writer" role to the service account. This can be done through the Cloud Console or through the command line.

To grant the "Artifact Registry Writer" role to the service account through the Cloud Console, follow these steps:

1-Go to the IAM & Admin page in the Cloud Console

2-Select the project that contains the Artifact Registry instance you are trying to upload artifacts to

3-Click "Add"

4-In the "New members" field, enter the email address of the service account

5- In the "Role" field, search for "Artifact Registry Writer"

6-Select the "Artifact Registry Writer" role from the list

7-Click "Save"

Comment: I am able to do it from my base system I am facing issue while doing it with Jenkins